# How to remove a UIWindow?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, uiwindow

I thought it was easy as `[myWindow resignKeyWindow]` and `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` but I guess not… Would you guys know what to do?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain/elaborate a little bit more what you are upto? As the question is not too clear. May be I am wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do not invoke `-resignKeyWindow` directly, it was meant to be overridden to execute some code when your UIWindows gets removed. In order to remove old window you need to create new instance of UIWindow and make it `-makeKeyAndVisible`, the old window will resign its key status. In iOS 4 it will even garbage collect your old *UIWindow*, provided you don't have any references to it. Doing this in iOS 3.x would have disastrous effects. Warned ya.

Comment: This indeed changes which window is the keyWindow, but doesn't seem to be removing it from application.windows....

Comment: Custom Window's superview is null. Just set it's hidden to NO

Comment: this the answer below (from Nikolai Ruhe) tells you how to actually remove a window

Comment: I answered this question two years before Nikolai Ruhe, before even ARC came into existence.

Answer (score 97):

The correct way to hide a window is to set the `hidden` property to YES. To remove it from UIApplication's `windows` property you just release the window (in ARC you set all references to nil).

Of course you would want to have another window in place at this time.

Comment: can't work now , ios 12 ,  
seems like can't remove it from UIApplication's windows after it makeKeyWindow.

Comment: It is not removing keywindow anymore and the list keeps growing. Any other ideas?

Comment: any feedback @adev ?

Comment: @JERC, nope. I couldn't find any solution. I am just hiding it for now and it is not released from that list too.

Comment: Having a strong reference to the window and then setting reference to nil when done is enough in iOS 13 to switch control back to the initial window.

Comment: It unfortunately still stays in the application's `windows` property

Comment: For me, the window does not *immediately* leave the `windows` property, but after a short interval it is indeed removed. But you do need to call `makeKeyAndVisible()` on another window.

Answer (score 15):

Here is how you can remove `UIWindow` on iOS 13 in a backward-compatible way. Tested on iOS 12, iOS 13, iPadOS with multi-window support:

```swift
extension UIWindow {
    func dismiss() {
        isHidden = true

        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            windowScene = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
// Detect key window
let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }

// Dismiss key window (if any)
keyWindow?.dismiss()
```

Comment: yep, it works, set window's windowScene to nil will removed from application's windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This extension helped me in some more cases:

```
/// Removes window from windows stack
func remove() {
    rootViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    rootViewController = nil
    isHidden = true
    
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/59988501/4124265
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        windowScene = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the window from the app delegate. However you can remove any custom windows created.

To remove the window you must first provide a replacement. So we get the default window.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

We now have access to the default window via the app delegate's `window` property.

Now get the original or custom navigation controller. Assign self to `rootViewController`.

Calling `makeKeyandVisible` removes any windows and assigns the app delegate's window as the key window. Set rootViewController to the navigation controller you just created and you are good to go!

```
DEMONavigationController *demoNav = [[DEMONavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];
[appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = demoNav;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any window other than app window, use it ..

```
let mainWindow = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window
mainWindow??.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score -9):

I have the same issue, it may helps.

You needs to destroy all strong ref before remove and dealloc a windows, especially the rootWindowController. I think below code is enough to delete any window:

```
[self.window.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
self.window.rootViewController = nil;
[self.window resignKeyWindow];
[self.window removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: As mentioned in some of the other posts, you shouldn't call `resignKeyWindow` directly.